# PHP for loop optimization

Tags: php, optimization

I've read up on some of the different optimizations that can be done with `for` loops in PHP, and would like to gauge your opinion on this:

```
for ($x = 0; $x < 50000000; ++$x) {
}
```

What else could I do, in this basic example, to speed it up? Would Zend Optimizer help with something so basic? I know it seems silly and not a real use-case, but it's of particular interest to me.

Comment: Isn't it what's inside the loop decides the speed?

Comment: Basically you can't do nothing. Even making $x++ instead of ++$x will slow down it... :)

Answer (score 5):

Your loop currently does absolutely *nothing*, so it's as optimized as it's ever going to be. You need to worry about what goes on *inside* the loop, not supposedly optimizing a language construct.

The only advice that can be given to "optimize" a `for` loop declaration is to avoid using something like a `count()` function in the comparison since it might get needlessly re-evaluated 50 million times. ie:

```
$count = count($hugeArray);
for( $i=0; $i<$count; $i++ ) {
  //actual code
}
```

Otherwise you should be ***FAR*** more concerned with the code inside your loop. Are there other loops inside your loops? Recursive calls? Blocking/locking operations? Streamlining the code between the `{` and `}` will get you ***FAR*** better returns than worrying about `for` using a few dozen extra clock cycles every day.

Comment: Thanks for your words Sammitch. The reason I broke down my question to such a basic, seemingly trivial, example, was because I have optimized the inner workings of the loop already. I am wondering if something like Zend Optimizer can in fact speed up a construct itself.

Answer (score 1):

Focus on readable maintainable code. Micro optimization is generally a bad thing because it leads to unreadable code. Check out what Jeff Atwood (stackexchange co-founder) has to say about it: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html